If a set has a "small enough" Lebesgue measure, does the set of points "close enough" to it have a "small enough" Lebesgue measure too?
If a set has a "small enough" Lebesgue measure, can we say that the set of points "close enough" to it will have a "small enough" Lebesgue measure too? Details below.
Let $\lambda$ denote the Lebesgue measure.
Suppose $E \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$. $E$ is compact and convex, $\lambda(E)<\infty$. Further, $A \subseteq E$, $\lambda(A)<\epsilon\lambda(E)$ for some $\epsilon>0$.
What is the tightest upper bound on the Lebesgue measure of the following set?
$$B:=\{x \in E:d(x,A)\leq \delta\}$$
where $d(x,A):=\inf\limits_{y \in A} d(x,y)$ where $d(\cdot,\cdot)$ is the Euclidean metric on $\mathbb{R}^2$. Clearly, $B \supseteq A$.
I would like to buttress that we know nothing more about $A$ than the fact that it has a small enough Lebesgue measure. In other words, it is allowed to be all sorts of "not nice".
For the sake of completeness, I would also like to add that question closest to this question I found is this.

You aren't really asking any concrete question so it's hard for me to say, but wouldn't a dense countable subset of $E$ contradict any nice upper bound? If $A$ however has a nice boundary, you could maybe try to relate it's length to $B\backslash A$?

The closure of $A$ can be as big as $E$ itself, even when $A$ is countable.  Where did this question come from?

That is exactly my confusion @BrianMoehring

Related though incomplete for these purposes

Again, where did the question come from?  If it's your creation, perhaps there's a natural assumption you're missing.  If it's a textbook, perhaps we can find errata.  Absent that info, however, I don't have the insight to help.

@BrianMoehring I'm stuck in an economics problem and it's a part of that so yes it's almost my creation, and I think we need more assumptions on the nature of $A$, as you correctly observed.

If $A$ is closed in $E$ then you get at least $\lambda(B_\delta)\to\lambda(A)$ for $\delta\to 0$ (where $B_\delta={x\in E: d(x,A)\le\delta$).  But I doubt that this qualitative result can be turned into a quantitative form for general $A$. Note that $B_\delta$ is the same for $A$ and its closure.

Seems to be related: Measure of a "tightened" set?

Take $E=[0,1]^2$. So, $E \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$, $E$ is compact and convex, and $\lambda(E)<\infty$. Take $A = [0,1]^2 \cap (\Bbb Q \times \Bbb Q)$. So, $A \subseteq E$, $\lambda(E)=1$, and $\lambda(A)=0<\epsilon = \epsilon\lambda(E)$ for some $\epsilon>0$. For any $\delta >0$,
$$B:={x \in E:d(x,A)\leq \delta} = E$$
So, without any additional conditions on $E$ or $A$, the tightest upper bound on the Lebesgue measure of $B$ is $\lambda(E)$.

@Jochen This is super helpful. Thank you so much!
